# Is there a way to supress printstacktrace() only for a certain package in Java?

Tags: java, spring, logging

I'm having a problem where a certain external dependency unfortunately using printstackTrace() instead of logging for certain exceptions. These exceptions can be ignored on our side, they don't affect the functionality of the module the dependency is used with.

However printstacktrace() fills up our log and its just very ugly and it can also have security implications.

Is there a way to supress these only for the package of the dependency? Obviously we do not want to turn off console logging all together just because of this.

Thank you

Comment: That's awful!  My advice ... ditch that badly written dependency, or if you have access to the source code, fix it.  Competent Java programmers have known not to log exceptions like that since circa 2000.

Comment: But to answer your question, AFAIK there isn't a way.

Comment: Unfortunately we dont have access to the source code and there is no way around using it at the moment.

Comment: Well, you will just have to put up with the ugliness.  (But I seriously doubt that security will be impacted.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to suppress `printstacktrace()` only for a certain package in Java?

There is no easy way to do this.  Certainly, there is no support in the Java SE class libraries for this, and (AFAIK<sup>1</sup>) nothing that directly does this in any 3rd-party library ... or tool.

My suggestions:

1. Ditch the dependency.  Replace it with something better / newer.  It has been normal practice in the Java world for the past 20 years to use logging frameworks for reporting internal errors, etc.  The fact that your dependency doesn't ... is a reflection on its quality.
2. Lean on the dependency supplier / vendor to fix the problem<sup>2</sup>.
3. If you have access to the source code, fix it yourself.
4. Put up with the ugliness.
5. If you are willing to put in a lot of effort, **it might be possible** to reverse engineer the dependency code to find the `printStackTrace()` callsites and patch them to do something more appropriate.  In theory, you could even do this as the bytecodes are being loaded.

I seriously doubt that there is a *real* issue with security.  Even if end users / hackers can see the stack traces, it is unlikely that they can get much useful information from them.  And if this *is* a real issue, you could *obfuscate* your application codebase ...

---

<sup>1 - If anyone knows of a library or tool that *specifically* deals with this scenario, please comment!

2 - My guess is that this won't work: they probably don't care enough to fix it.  Indeed, if this is representative of the overall quality of their code, they shouldn't still be in business!</sup>

Comment: You could replace `System.err` with your own `PrintWriter` (or whatever it is) that masks things that look like stack traces. Or that looks at the current thread's call stack to mask certain caller patterns. But that's a level of hackage that I'd never want to see in production code.